# Draw a shape and save it to the database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, paint

i want   drawing shape with  mouse by user in asp.net 
and Compatible with IE8 . i want drawing and save image in database.

Comment: you can use libraries http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/drawing/10-best-javascript-drawing-and-canvas-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 provides canvas element. More information can be found here -->    https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Track the user interaction on the client. Allow the client to send this data to the server, and save this in the database. Create the image on the server based on the users interaction, and provide a reference to the image on the client. How you create this image is server language dependent, see here for a .NET example:
   http://www.developerfusion.com/article/2569/creating-images-on-the-fly-with-aspnet/
2. You can't use Canvas in IE8 as it's not supported. However this can re-create that canvas functionality: http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/. Or you could use a flash-based alternative.